# Why forms validations for inner divs do not work inside another div?

Tags: angular

I have this HTML template:

```
<div class="ui raised segment">
    <h2 clas="ui header">Demo Form: with validations (explicit)</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="myForm"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)"
        class="ui form">
        <div class="field"
            [class.error]="!sku.valid && sku.touched">
            <label for="skuInput">SKU</label>
            <input type="text" 
                id="skuInput" 
                placeholder="SKU" [formControl]="sku">
            <div *ngIf="!sku.valid" 
                class="ui error message">SKU is invalid</div>
            <div *ngIf="sku.hasError('required')"
                class="ui error message">SKU is required</div>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="!myForm.valid"
            class="ui error message">Form is invalid</div>

        <button type="submit" class="ui button primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The two `div`s inside the `div` with `class="field"` do not appear when the field with `id="skuInput"` is invalid.

I have put the two `div`s outside the outer most `div` and they work as expected.

Why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

`sku` in your template is not what you think it is; namely it is not a reference to your form control.

As a matter of fact, I get a number of console errors with your stock template.

We'll need to keep in mind that we're using Reactive Forms and be more explicit than the Template Driven forms and directly reference the control:

```
<div class="field" [class.error]="!myForm.controls.sku.valid &&
    myForm.controls.sku.touched">
    <label for="skuInput">SKU</label>
    <input type="text" id="skuInput" 
              placeholder="SKU" formControlName="sku">
    <div *ngIf="!myForm.controls.sku.valid" 
              class="ui error message">SKU is invalid</div>
    <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.sku.hasError('required')"
              class="ui error message">SKU is required</div>
</div>
```

I also changed `[formControl]` which requires the actual reference to the form control to be on the right hand side to `formControlName` which allows for the nicer looking syntax which echoed what you were using.

[Plunkify](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Ru9KeKiJFnhU2ju89Xn?p=preview)